# Finding count for a Period in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with :

```
 user_id | order_date 
---------+------------
      12 | 2014-03-23
      12 | 2014-01-24
      14 | 2014-01-26
      16 | 2014-01-23
      15 | 2014-03-21
      20 | 2013-10-23
      13 | 2014-01-25
      16 | 2014-03-23
      13 | 2014-01-25
      14 | 2014-03-22
```

A Active user is someone who has logged in last 12 months.
Need output as

```
Period | count of Active user
----------------------------
Oct-2013 - 1 
Jan-2014 - 5 
Mar-2014 - 10
```

The Jan 2014 value -  includes Oct -2013 1 record and 4 non duplicate record for Jan 2014)

Comment: Update with the query you have tried.

Comment: which rdbms are you using? date functions vary across rdbms

Comment: It looks like it is better to calculate it server-side. I cannot imagine a SQL query without several nested selects \ joins \ where.

Comment: I know, but can we do it in sql? Help would be really appreciated

Comment: Actually for Mar-2014 , count is 9 instead of 10 if you avoid duplicate

Comment: i think mysql + php can acheive this ..!!

Comment: How do you keep track of the logged datetimes? Is there a field in a users table or is the a table with Every log that took place? If you post your show create tables for the 3 tables that are involve I can help you with a query that does the job

Comment: @MIke - the table has 2 columns,  user_id and order_date. The period for the output is calculated from order_date.

Comment: so a user is active if they made an order in the past 12 months or when they were logged in the past 12 months?

Comment: @Mike yes thats right(if they have made an order in the past 12 months)  and it should be distinct for a particular period.

Comment: I do not think you have defined the requirement correctly. There is only 6 distinct users in your data set. How come the number can bet 10 (or 9)?

Comment: could you please confirm the answer, so all user know this is solved. thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can use a variable to calculate the running total of active users:

```
SELECT Period,
       @total:=@total+cnt AS `Count of Active Users`
FROM (       
SELECT CONCAT(MONTHNAME(order_date), '-', YEAR(order_date)) AS Period,
       COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS cnt       
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY Period
ORDER BY YEAR(order_date), MONTH(order_date) ) t,
(SELECT @total:=0) AS var
```

The subquery returns the number of *distinct* active users per Month/Year. The outer query uses `@total` variable in order to calculate the running total of active users' count.

[**Fiddle Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b5d1/10)

Comment: I do not think it is a right answer, even though it gets upvoted a lot. Just have a look at the initial data. There are only 6 distinct users in the whole table. It is logically impossible to have the 9 as the number of users in March

Comment: @cha It is a matter of requirement interpretation. I think what the OP wants is count number of *distinct users within a month/year period*, *then* calculate the running total of this sum. Only the OP of course can help us clear this thing out.

Comment: I think however that logically it is incorrect to apply the running total rule to such case. The running total is more applicable to financial reports. It is either the OP did not understand the requirements from the management, ot it is not the user_id but something else

Comment: @ Giorgos yes this answer is correct but I think need a slight modification. For Ex: the req I had given was not right in first place, the query given by @cha below solved my problem, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

I've got two queries that do the thing. I am not sure which one's the fastest. Check them aginst your database:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42577/26)

**Query 1**:

```
select per.yyyymm,
(select count(DISTINCT o.user_id) from orders o where o.order_date >= 
(per.yyyymm - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) and o.order_date < per.yyyymm + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as `count`
from
(select DISTINCT LAST_DAY(order_date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH as yyyymm
from orders) per
order by per.yyyymm
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42577/26/0)**:

```
|                    yyyymm | count |
|---------------------------|-------|
| October, 01 2013 00:00:00 |     1 |
| January, 01 2014 00:00:00 |     5 |
|   March, 01 2014 00:00:00 |     6 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y-%m'),
(select count(DISTINCT o.user_id) from orders o where o.order_date >= 
 (LAST_DAY(o1.order_date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 13 MONTH) and 
 o.order_date <= LAST_DAY(o1.order_date)) as `count`
from orders o1
group by DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y-%m')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42577/26/1)**:

```
| DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y-%m') | count |
|----------------------------------|-------|
|                          2013-10 |     1 |
|                          2014-01 |     5 |
|                          2014-03 |     6 |
```

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I could do is this:

```
SELECT Date, COUNT(*) as ActiveUsers
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT userId, CONCAT(YEAR(order_date), "-", MONTH(order_date)) as Date
    FROM `a` 
    ORDER BY Date
)
AS `b`
GROUP BY Date
```

The output is the following:

```
|    Date | ActiveUsers |
|---------|-------------|
| 2013-10 |           1 |
|  2014-1 |           4 |
|  2014-3 |           4 |
```

Now, for every row you need to sum up the number of active users in previous rows.
For example, here is the code in C#.

```
int total = 0;
while (reader.Read())
{ 
    total += (int)reader['ActiveUsers'];
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} active users", reader['Date'].ToString(), reader['ActiveUsers'].ToString());
}
```

By the way, for the March of 2014 the answer is 9 because one row is duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but thise doesn't handle the last part: The Jan 2014 value - includes Oct -2013

```
select TO_CHAR(order_dt,'MON-YYYY'), count(distinct User_ID ) cnt from [orders] 
where User_ID  in 
(select User_ID from
 (select a.User_ID from  [orders] a,
(select a.User_ID,count (a.order_dt) from [orders] a 
where a.order_dt > (select max(b.order_dt)-365 from [orders] b where a.User_ID=b.User_ID)
group by a.User_ID
having count(order_dt)>1) b
where a.User_ID=b.User_ID) a
)
group by TO_CHAR(order_dt,'MON-YYYY');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I think you are looking for

```
SET @cnt = 0;
SELECT Period, @cnt := @cnt + total_active_users AS total_active_users
FROM (
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%b-%Y') AS Period , COUNT( id) AS total_active_users
  FROM t
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%b-%Y')
  ORDER BY order_date
) AS t
```

This is the output that I get

```
Period      total_active_users
Oct-2013    1
Jan-2014    6
Mar-2014    10
```

You can also do COUNT(DISTINCT id) to get the unique Ids only

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/179c4/8)